# Swipe gestures for mobile website

Tags: javascript, mobile, gestures

I'm looking to create swipe gestures for this mobile website prototype I'm working on: http://patthorntonfiles.com/snk_mobile/

The idea is that when you swipe left across a story on the homepage, four icons would appear: email story, Facebook, Twitter and like. If you've used Sparrow for the iPhone, I'm looking for a very similar gesture. I'm looking for a standards-based way to do this. The prototype already uses jQuery for some other parts.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you're looking for but search for JS Swipe Libraries. I just used [HammerJS](http://eightmedia.github.com/hammer.js/) on my last project.

Javascript example:

```
var hammer = new Hammer(document.getElementById("news_article"));
hammer.ondragend = function(ev) {
    $('.icons').fadeIn();
};
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it can do what I want it to do.

I'm trying to make this menu of icons appear when a user swipes over a story on the homepage: http://www.patthorntonfiles.com/snk_mobile/shareicons.php

I haven't gotten it to work yet. Any suggestions?